# Toolbar doesn't appear at the bottom of WKWebView

Tags: swift, xcode

I'd like to make an iOS browser app using `WKWebView`. Currently I can display an webpage on the entire view.
Now I'm trying to add a `Toolbar` at the bottom of WKWebView, but it doesn't appear on the view. I placed a `Toolbar` object on Storyboard and attached it to my code, but only `WKWebView` shows up on the entire view, without a toolbar.
How can I implement the `Toolbar` in the correct way?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var WKToolbar: UIToolbar!

    var startUrl = "https://www.apple.com"
    var pageTitle: String?
    var requestUrl: String?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        if let url = URL(string: startUrl) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func prevBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if webView.canGoForward {
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

[my Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Aq1Z.png)

Comment: could you please post a picture of your storyboard as well?

Comment: added a pic's link.

Comment: The dark grey view is `webView`, right?

Comment: Yes, it's `webView`.

Comment: You just need to remove `self.view = webView` and you'll be fine. Because that way you're replacing the whole view that contains both the web view and the tool bar with the web view only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved. Following Mo Abdul-Hameed's advice, I removed this part, and the `WKWebView` and `Toolbar` worked properly.
I think this part had replaced the setting made by WebView object on Storyboard.

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
self.view = webView
```

Comment: It's worked for me but remember that don't override loadView()